# Constraint Layout version > 2.0.1 does not follow guildline rules

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am experiencing layout issues when trying to use the latest versions of constraint layout. It seems to not follow guideline rules. Is this a bug in the library? My project uses many guidelines and to change every one of them would be a huge pain. Anyone know if there is a work around of am I doing this wrong? This layout issue seems to happen in versions greater than constraint layout 2.0.1.

**Constraint layout v 1.1.3**
[image: Constraint layout v 1.1.3]

**Constraint Layout v 2.0.4** -  the location icon is behind my widget constraint layout
[image: Constraint Layout v 2.0.4]

**MainActivity layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Please Type Something"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <requestFocus />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mic_container"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/mic_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/mic_icon_guideline">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:button="@drawable/navigation_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/mic_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="28dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/attachment_icon_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/button_add_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:button="@drawable/add_location_button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_remove_location"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/button_remove_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:button="@drawable/remove_location_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_add_location"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test_constraint_project"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *RelativeLayout* `mic_container` has the following constraints:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
```

It doesn't seem right that the top of one view should be constrained to the bottom of another and the bottom of the first view should be constrainted to the top of the second. This is really an invalid situation and I think that you are seeing *ConstraintLayout* resolving this differently between the two versions.

If you state the following as constraints:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_message_input"
```

I think that you will see `mic_container` positioned appropriately. You will have to determine if this solves all of your problems or not.